# Is the verb *released* incorrectly used with the helping verb did?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Grammarly is correcting me:

> Actually, I did not **released** it in a new name because it was supposed for me to take over the maintenance.

It is saying I should use **release** instead of **released**. Does is Grammarly right?

> It appears that the verb **released** is incorrectly used with the helping verb did. Consider changing it to the base form to **release**.
>
> Do, does, or did can be used as a helping verb in certain constructions. They can add emphasis to the main verb, form a question, or express a negative (when used with not). The main verb in these constructions always uses the base form when combined with do, does, or did.

Answer (score 1):

Did not+verb(first form)

> I did not release it

is grammatical

Answer (score 1):

Verbs used with *do* are not inflected (changed in form) for time or number or person, and cannot take aspects like the perfect or progressive. If it's coming after any form of *do* or *do not*, any change for time, number or person happens to *do*. You always use a bare infinitive after *do*, including *does*, *did*, *does not*, *did not*, *do not*, and contracted versions of the same.

> I **did not release** it.